# Esconder navbar quando item for clicado

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav-bar

Estou desenvolvendo um site cujo menu é o navbar com dropdown do bootstrap 4. Quando visualizo o site numa tela menor, a nav é substituída pelo botão hamburguer e só é "ativada" quando esse botão é clicado. Entretanto, eu quero que ela seja "desativada" quando algum item do menu for clicado. Por exemplo, se eu clico em "Contato", além da tela rolar pra parte de contato, eu quero que o menu suba e fique apenas o botão ali em cima.

```
<header>
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <img id="icone" src="imgs/logoBranca.png" height="35" alt="Logo da Clara Quitutes & Cia">
    <a id="nome" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Clara Quitutes & Cia</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#inicio">Início</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Serviços</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#bolos">Bolos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#salgados">Salgados</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#bebidas">Bebidas</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#docinhos">Docinhos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#quitutes">Quitutes</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#empratados">Empratados</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#opcoes-saudaveis">Opções Saudáveis</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Garçonete/Copeira</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contato">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Tentei usar essa função no JS (achei no GitHub), mas não funcionou. O que há de errado no código?

```
//Função para o menu subir quando um item for clicado
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-nav li.-collapse a").click(function(event){
      $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
  });
```

Há alguma outra maneira que eu possa fazer isso? Não estou usando jQuery no projeto e não gostaria de utilizar somente para isso por ser muito pesado, então, preferencialmente, que a sugestão de solução possa ser desenvolvida em JS ou até mesmo CSS. Quero o seguinte:

Menu sem cliques

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Menu quando clico no hamburguer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, quando eu clicar em algum item da lista (nesse caso, "home", "users" ou "places"), o menu volta a ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas o bootstrap é quase totalmente dependente do jQuery, principalmente em NAVBAR, menus dropdowns e carousel.

Comment: Não tem problema me enviarem uma sugestão com jQuery. Eu só PREFIRO que seja com css ou javascript.

Comment: mas o problema não tá no meu html ou css. To usando um navbar do bootstrap. Se vc for aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/ e testar qualquer navbar como mobile, ao clicar no menu hamburguer e depois em um item dele, vai ver que ele não fecha. Quero saber como posso mudar isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta disparar um gatilho `.click()` no botão hambúrguer quando um link for clicado, exceto o que possui apenas um `#` no `href`, pois esse link abre um submenu dropdown, não é uma âncora (ex., o link "Serviços").

Para isso você seleciona todos os links do menu, EXCETO o que possui apenas o `#` no `href` usando a pseudo-classe `:not`, e cria um evento `click` para cada um. Ao clicar em algum deles irá disparar o gatilho `.click()` no botão, fazendo o menu fechar:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var links = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav li a:not([href='#'])");
   for(var x=0; x<links.length; x++){
      links[x].onclick = function(){
         document.querySelector("button.navbar-toggler").click();
      }
   }
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var links = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav li a:not([href='#'])");
   for(var x=0; x<links.length; x++){
      links[x].onclick = function(){
         document.querySelector("button.navbar-toggler").click();
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<header>
  Abra o menu e clique, por exemplo, em "Contato":
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a id="nome" class="navbar-brand" href="#">Clara Quitutes & Cia</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#inicio">Início</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Serviços</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#bolos">Bolos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#salgados">Salgados</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#bebidas">Bebidas</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#docinhos">Docinhos</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#quitutes">Quitutes</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#empratados">Empratados</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="servicos.html#opcoes-saudaveis">Opções Saudáveis</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Garçonete/Copeira</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contato">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="contato">
   contato
</div>
```

> Agora, seu jQuery não funciona porque seu seletor está incorreto:

```
".navbar-nav li.-collapse a"
```

Deveria ser:

```
".navbar-nav li a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa assim que funciona perfeitamente, caso mais alguém tenha esse problema. Abraço.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Para esconder pode utilizar o seguinte codigo `

```js
$('id ou class do navbar').hide()
```

`

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Acredito que agora tenha ficado mais clara, rs

Answer (score -3):

Parabéns para mim deu certo dessa forma

```
// Hide Menu
var hideMenu = function() {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
       var links = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav li a:not([href='#'])");
       for(var x=0; x<links.length; x++){
          links[x].onclick = function(){
             document.querySelector("button.navbar-toggler").click();
          }
       }
    });

};
hideMenu();
```

Comment: Sua "resposta" é exatamente como [outra acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/323296/100416). Se deseja agradecer, faça o [tour] e entenda como o StackOverflow funciona.